# How to take automated database dump of rethinkdb inside container?

Tags: docker, rethinkdb, docker-container

I am running rethinkdb inside docker container with bind mount (Which is bind with the host).

When we are running rethinkdb without the container, we shall take database dump with shell scripting very easily.

But when we are running rethinkdb in the docker container, where I wanted to take the dump with shell scripting.

We are running rethinkdb inside the container, so all rethinkdb commands run inside the container (not on the host system).

so How to set up automated dumps of rethinkdb running inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same script that you use normally when the database is not containerized. You can achieve that by copying the script into the container and then executing it inside.

```
docker cp dump.sh <container-name>:<script-container-path>
docker exec -it <container-name> <script-container-path>
```

The above commands will copy the dump script and execute it inside the container.

The resulting dump will be inside the container, which you can copy back into the host using `docker cp <container-name>:<dump-path> .`